# Reference a slot inside the ViewModel of an Aurelia component

Tags: aurelia

Let's say you have the following component:

```
export class Message {
    messageTxt: string = "";

    attached() {
       // reference the slot HTMLElement here somehow
    }
}
```

with the following template:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <slot name="trigger">
      </slot>

      <div>${messageTxt}</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

As the comment in the code implies, I'm wondering how to access the `<slot>` element in the ViewModel. I've tried adding a `ref` attribute to it but it's `undefined`.

I've also tried adding a parent to it, putting the `ref` on the parent and getting the slot `HTMLElement` by accessing the parent's direct child. It worked, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Just to be clear, I need the element that's going to replace the `<slot>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the name of the *tag* that is going to be in the `<slot>`, you can use the `@child` resolver. For example:

**Message's ViewModel**

```
import {child} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Element1 {
  @child('p') myP;

  attached() {
    console.log(this.myP);
  }
}
```

**Message's View**

```
<template>
   <slot></slot>
</template>
```

**Usage**

```
<element1>
   <p>test 1 2 3</p>
</element1>
```

Use `@children` for a collection of elements:

**Message's ViewModel**

```
import {children} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Element1 {
  @children('ps') myPs = [];

  attached() {
    console.log(this.myPs);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<element1>
   <p>test 1 2 3</p>
   <p>test 1 2 3</p>
   <p>test 1 2 3</p>
</element1>
```

---

If you don't know the name of the *tag*, you can inject the element and iterate over the `children` property. For instance:

**Message's View**

```
<template>
  <slot name="1"></slot>
  <slot name="2"></slot>
</template>
```

**Message's ViewModel**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class Element1 {

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    //iterate over this.element.children;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<template>
  <require from="./element1"></require>

  <element1>
    <p slot="1">sadfasdf</p>
    <p slot="2">asdfsadfasd</p>
  </element1>
</template>
```